# Is there any direct API to find the matching items for the same index in a variant of the order var(a,b)?

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I've got a variant let's say **var(9,175)** (obtained using ADO object for reading excel) where 9 represents the columns and 175 represents the rows, filled with some data.

1. How can I retrieve entire row data (for each column value the row number will be same, obvious) based on 3 columns (for the same row) taken from other workbook. So, the matching keys will be these 3 column values from other workbook.
2. I don't want to perform the looping operation, as it'll be time-consuming.

Example: In variant **var** I've got some data at **2nd** row as:

```
#125    a    [68]    :1    [197]    :2    1    1645    123
```

From other workbook, I took the data as:

```
[68]    :1    [197]
```

Based on these 3 values,
How can I directly get the data of the 2nd row entirely based on some Find or Match commands?

Comment: In VBA, well designed loops are often the most efficient solution

Comment: @chrisneilsen the problem is i can not have 4 loops running together to match data, one from ADO variant, another from second worksheet.

Comment: `Filter()` See help.

Comment: @Noodles In its description, it says, "The function will throw an error if the sourcearray is either Null or multidimensional". In my case the array is multidimensional.

Comment: how is this being generated, and what is the overall process here?

Comment: Have you tried the loops to see what the performance is (your array is not very large)? Why do you say you cannot have 4 loops running together?

Comment: @MacroMarc It is generated from an excel database where i have got 9 columns and 175 rows, using ADO and sql query. I am using getrows() method to get this variant. the problem is to access the entire row based on some columns by either finding or matching operation, if it does exist.

Comment: @ChipsLetten I am not really sure but may be because of formatting the excel even takes time to open. array might not be large but the comparison of data (rows and columns) in two different workbooks shall have the need for 4 loops to iterate through each row and column.'

Comment: It is best for a question to show the code that is being used around the problem part. Then we can help to fill in code. Couldn't you just return the desired rows from a SQL subquery an transform into another recordset?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do exactly, but if you know the row-number in the array that you want the entire row from, then you can use the `Worksheet.Index` function.

Here's an example using a dummy 2D array:

```
Sub test()

  'Assign a 2D array
  Dim my2DArray() As Variant
  my2DArray() = [{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}]

  Const DESIRED_ROW As Long = 2

  'Use the Worksheet.Index function to extract an individual row
  Dim myRow() As Variant
  myRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(my2DArray, DESIRED_ROW, 0)

  Debug.Print Join(myRow, ",") 'Prints 4,5,6

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to search for a row by indexing! i need to take the data of the row by searching for particular columns in that row. Hope it makes it clear to you now.